# Why do I get this compile error in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, compiler-errors

I get the following error:

```
quicksort(int[],int,int)cannot be applied to(int[])
```

When I compile this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sort {

public static void main(String[] args){

Random rand = new Random();
int[] tab = new int[10];

for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
tab[i] = rand.nextInt(100);

System.out.println("Before: ");
show(tab);

quicksort (tab);
System.out.println("After: ");
show(tab);
  }
}
static void quicksort(int tab[], int x, int y) {

        int i,j,v,temp;

        i=x;
        j=y;
        v=tab[(x+y) / 2];
        do {
            while (tab[i]<v) 
                i++;
            while (v<tab[j]) 
                j--;
            if (i<=j) {
                temp=tab[i];
                tab[i]=tab[j];
                tab[j]=temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        while (i<=j);
        if (x<j) 
            quicksort(tab,x,j);
        if (i<y) 
            quicksort(tab,i,y);
    }


static void show (int tab[]) {
for (int i = 0; i <tab.length; i++) {
System.out.println(tab[i]);

  }
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `x` and `y` to be when you call it without specifying them?

Answer (score 17):

Just after the line to print out "before", you have:

```
quicksort (tab);
```

The function you designed needs three arguments. You can either add the extra arguments:

```
quicksort (tab, 0, tab.length - 1)
```

Or add a new function such as:

```
public quicksort(int[]) {
  quicksort(tab, 0, tab.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

the function "quicksort" that you define asks for 3 parameters, but you are only providing one.

Answer (score 6):

Because your quicksort function has 3 parameters, but your call gives only one.

Edit: second :(

Answer (score 2):

your code should call

```
quicksort (tab,0,10);
```

In your outer calll, so you can sort the list.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you're writing code in, I strongly recommend using an IDE if you haven't adopted one already.  Particularly [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages) for Java.

Eclipse would underline the offending line of code and make some suggestions to you, (in addition to offering code completion).  A text editor, like JEdit does not.

Note: I've been told IntelliJ is good, but you can't beat Eclipse's price (free).

Answer (score 0):

BTW: You could just use Arrays.sort() which is a built in function. You wouldn't write a function like this in real life. (only as homework)